# Cómo evitar que el frontend genere peticiones duplicadas a mi servidor heroku?

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, heroku

estoy haciendo una aplicación con react native y adonis js en el Frontend, el servidor lo tengo en Heroku, el problema es que aparentemente  el frontend está enviando peticiones duplicadas al servidor y digo aparentemente por que aunque el servidor las registra el comportamiento del frontend es el esperado, anexo el metodo con el que hago las peticiones y la consola que heroku me muestra... No espero que me digan exactamente que hacer, más bien que me digan por qué puede ocasionarse esto y por qué estoy fallando, gracias de antemano

```js
//optenerposts
    getposts = async()=>{
        if(this.state.active == true && this.state.find == false){
            await this.setState({active: false, loadmore: true})
            await this.setState(prevState => ({ page: prevState.page + 1 }));
            const allposts = await functions.getposts(this.props.navigation.state.params.dato, this.state.page,
                                                        this.state.finder)
            switch(allposts.response){
                case true :
                    let arr = allposts.data 
                    if(Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length){
                        let push = this.state.posts.concat(arr)
                        this.setState({posts : push, active: true, loadmore: false})
                    }
                break    
            }
        }
    }
    // peticion de axios
    
    
const getposts = async(category, page)=>{
    let r = {response : false}

    await axios.get(url+'/posts/'+category,{
        params: {
            foo: page
        }
    }).then(response =>{
        r = {response : true, data : response.data.data}
    }).catch(error=> {
        r= {response : false, data : error.response.data.message}
    })

    return r
}

//component did mount


    async componentDidMount(){
        if(Platform.OS == "android"){
            BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
        }
        await this.Change()
        await this.getposts()
        await this.props.navigation.addListener(
        'willFocus',
        async() => {
            this.refresh()
            await this.Change()
            await this.getposts()
        })
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Durante `componentDidMount()` se esta llamando dos veces a `getPosts()`,
una vez durante la carga y otra vez al ganar foco (`willFocus`)

```
async componentDidMount(){
    if(Platform.OS == "android"){
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    }
    await this.Change()
    await this.getposts()
    await this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'willFocus',
    async() => {
        this.refresh()
        await this.Change()
        await this.getposts()
    })
}
```

Durante la carga vez quiza no es necesario llamar a dicho metodo si `willFocus` siempre ocurrirá.

```
async componentDidMount(){
    if(Platform.OS == "android"){
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    }
    //remover llamadas directas a this.Change() y this.getposts()
    await this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'willFocus',
    async() => {
        this.refresh()
        await this.Change()
        await this.getposts()
    })
}
```

Comment: Acabo de intentar eso... Y sí, funcionó, es decir si se redujo considerablemente la cantidad de peticiones que hacía aún así  cuando se ejecuta el metodo hace dos o tres peticiones, provisionalmente le puse setTimeout pero no sé si esto sea correcto